How to Work with German Numbers directly in React Native?
One of my client wants react native mobile application to work with German format numbers. In German format they use comma symbol in place of decimal point to input or represent decimal numbers. I could not find any direct way to work with this format in react native.
I have completed the work with standard numbers and have implemented format conversion to replace comma in numbers with decimal point while saving them in database and also when performing calculations. Then I convert decimal numbers back to German format by replacing decimal point with comma in order to display numbers in app. I want to know if there is any direct way to work with numbers in German format or Australian format. Your reply will be highly valued.

1. Use Internationalization Libraries

Intl.NumberFormat: JavaScript's built-in Intl.NumberFormat can format numbers according to the locale you specify. For example:
const number = 1234567.89;
const formattedNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(number);
console.log(formattedNumber); // Output: "1.234.567,89"


React Native libraries: Libraries like react-intl or i18n-js can help with internationalization, including number formatting.

2. Third-Party Libraries

numeral.js: This library allows for custom formats and can handle different locales.
const numeral = require('numeral');
numeral.locale('de');
const formattedNumber = numeral(1234567.89).format('0,0.00');
console.log(formattedNumber);


react-native-localize: This library helps with locale detection and can be combined with Intl.NumberFormat or numeral.js for locale-specific formatting.

3. Custom Format Functions
If you want more control, you can write custom functions to handle formatting and parsing:
const toGermanFormat = (number) => number.toString().replace('.', ',');
const fromGermanFormat = (string) => parseFloat(string.replace(',', '.'));

